# How to animate an SVG circle around an ellipse

Tags: svg

This may be a duplicate of a similar question asked by Ruby several years ago, but following the suggestions posted has not resulted in a solution for me. Of course it could be me that is the problem.

I am trying to generate cycloid curves (circles rotating around other curves) BUT I would like to create the curve of a circle rotating around an ellipse - not a circle.

I can animate a circle to follow an elliptical path.

I can animate a circle to rotate about its center.

I need to do both animations simultaneously, but my object follows a path somewhere else in my viewbox.

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 700">
    <path id="OUT" d="M200,250
    a220,110 0 1,0 600,0
    a220,110 0 1,0 -600,0"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#ccc; stroke-width:2" />

    <g id="CC">
    <circle r=40 cx=200 cy=250 fill="none" stroke="black" stroke- width="2"/>
    <g id="C1">
        <circle r=5 cx=200 cy=250 fill="green"/>
    </g>
    <circle cx="240" cy="250" r="3" fill="blue" />
    </g>

    <animateTransForm
    xlink:href="#CC"
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML"
    type="rotate"
    from="0 200 250" to="360 200 250" begin="1s" dur="10s"
    additive="sum" />

    <animateTransform
    xlink:href="#CC"
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML"
    type="rotate"
    mpath xlink:href="#OUT"
    from="0 300 250" to="360 300 250"
    begin="1s" dur="10s" fill="freeze"
    additive="sum"/>

</svg>
```

Hopefully this will give someone an idea of my effort, and trigger a solution. Many thanks.
www.softouch.on.ca

Comment: What post are you referring to? Sounds weird that for such a task one talked about `<animateTransform>`, are you sure it wasn't `<animateMotion>`? Moreover when we see this weird `mpath` argument... Anyway, does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dna0v65s/) reproduce what you are after?

Comment: @Kaiido if it's a cycloid animation, the blue dot would stay on the largest ellipse and it would look like the circle is rolling round the large ellipse.

Comment: What is this mysterious question that Ruby asked?

Comment: @RobertLongson you are probably right, even though I still have trouble to get what it really means... Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/dna0v65s/1/)?  Anyway, my comment's main goal was to get more information as to what OP is talking about, since it could very well still be a duplicate of this *mysterious question* as you called it. Ah I think [I found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961817/svg-animation-of-a-circle-on-an-elliptical-path). and indeed, no `<animateTransform>` there.

Comment: Hello Kaiido, and YES that does exactly what I want. I will compare with my attempt to see where I was going off the track (no pun intended).

Comment: Woops, I meant Thank You to @RobertLongson for the Fiddle code. But Thank You to all who answered. There was not an answer to the original Ruby question, so I was using what she had posted with no joy.

Comment: Woops, I meant Thank You to @RobertLongson for the Fiddle code. But Thank You to all who answered. There was not an answer to the original Ruby question, so I was using what she had posted with no joy. The 'translation' was the piece I was missing, but now the question becomes - why is that necessary? Was my SVG definition wrong? Should I have used a 'viewBox'? On other things I've done this wasn't needed, so I am curious what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

- you just need to use animateMotion to apply line animation on any
  shape just set so animation can know in which line it has to walk
- because of [transform translate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400986/svg-position-text-relative-to-parent-g/26407441#26407441) i manually set transform
  translate, it will work without setting transform translate in
  circle
- i used css key frame animation to rotate small circle and both
  animation not working at a time so i added one layer(as `<g>` tag)
  inside main `<g>` tag

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" >
  <def>
    <style>
     @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        }

      }

        #extrag{
        transform-origin: left;
           animation: rotation 5s infinite linear;
           transform-origin: 201px 250px;
        }
    </style>
  </def>
    <path id="OUT" d="M200,250
    a220,110 0 1,0 600,0
    a220,110 0 1,0 -600,0"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#ccc; stroke-width:2" />

  <g id="CC" transform="translate(-190,-245)">
     <g id="extrag">
    <circle r=40 cx=200 cy=250 fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    <g id="C1" >
        <circle r=5 cx=200 cy=250 fill="green"/>
    </g>
    <circle cx="240" cy="250" r="3" fill="blue">
    </circle>

    </g>
         <animateMotion 
  xlink:href="#CC"
  attributeName="motion"
  attributeType="XML"
  additive="sum"
  dur="6s"
  repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#OUT"/>
  </animateMotion>
   </g>
  
  
</svg>
```